# How to get the current constant value from different constants value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

[image]

I set constraint constant for two different classes ,when i try to print the constant on wRhR(ipads) the first constant value is coming .

Always i am getting

```
  NSLog(@"this is constant %f",_txtbottomconstraints.constant);
```

**output :**

```
 this is constant 240.000000  //this output is am getting in ipad.
```

help me to get the current constant value thanks :)

Comment: are you printing for iPad?

Comment: @techloverr yes bro :(

Comment: @Hima but for ipad to its returning 240 ? whats to do

Comment: @Hima you wrote reversed statement

Comment: reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print in viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("constraint  : \(_txtbottomconstraints.constant)");
    }
```

Comment: I have given this to moderator that why downvote without reason?

Comment: they will look into this

Comment: yes it is use full can you give brief explanation about view will appear and others if possible.